# what is the FNN:knn return value?

Tags: r

This is a question about R, not about kNN. Basically, in examining some code, I came across the following incantation:

```
results <- (0:9)[knn(train, test, labels, k = 10, algorithm="cover_tree")]
```

I understand *what* it returns. I just don't understand the `(0:n)[<foo>]` notation in R. And I've tried other values instead of `0:9`, but can't seem to break this in a meaningful way, as well as done due diligence googling.

Can anyone explain this to a Python/Java/C programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, the code 0:9 returns a vector with values from 0 to 9. The square bracket notation is used for indexing into that vector:

> (0:9)[4] # returns the 4th element of the vector 0:9 (or 3)

In this case, because knn returns the classification of the test set as a factor, what this is effectively doing is mapping that classification into the integers from 0 to 9.

> (0:9)[1, 3, 1, 5] # returns a vector with 4 values, namely <0, 2, 0, 4>

Comment: Ah, got it. I just looked at `table(labels)` and see that they only range 0:9. Which explains why replacing the vector with something like `(0:20)` didn't change the result, but something like `(0:4)` returned about half NAs. Great answer!